# AWSS3Provider - ensure credentials error No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I'm trying to access a protected image from AWS S3 in react native, but i'm getting following error:

```
[WARN] 07:06.800 AWSS3Provider - ensure credentials error No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access
 ERROR  Error fetching the image: [Error: No credentials]
```

Here is what i'm doing:

amplify-config.js

```
export const awsConfiguration = {
  Storage: {
    AWSS3: {
      bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
      region: 'REGION',
      accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_ID',
      secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
      level: 'private'
    },
  },
};
```

in App.ts

```
import { awsConfiguration } from './amplify-config';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure(awsConfiguration);
```

I'm also generating a presigned url because i'm receiving from backend something like that :
'https://s3.bucket-name.com/compression-img/11ee-bbb5-a5d6898a-382c--00155dc60818.webp';

generate-s3-presigned-url.tsx

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

// Configure AWS credentials
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
  secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
  region: 'REGION',
});

// Function to generate a pre-signed URL
export function generateS3PresignedURL(imageUrl, expirationSeconds = 3600) {
  imageUrl =
    'https://s3.bucket-name.com/compression-img/11ee-bbb5-a5d6898a-382c--00155dc60818.webp';
  // Extract bucket and key from the provided URL
  
  const bucket = "s3.bucket-name.com"; // Assuming that 's3.bucket-name.com' is the S3 bucket hostname
  const key = "compression-img/11ee-bbb5-a5d6898a-382c--00155dc60818.webp"; // The rest of the URL is the key

  // Create an S3 object
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  // Generate a pre-signed URL
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    Expires: expirationSeconds,
  };

  return s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
}
```

the result is :

```
Pre-signed URL: https://s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/s3.bucket-name.com/compression-img/11ee-bbb5-a5d6898a-382c-00155dc60818.webp?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ACCESS_KEYaws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231018T075941Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=SIGNATURE-SignedHeaders=host
```

and finally i'm trying to access the image like that :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, View } from 'react-native';
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';

export function ImageDisplay() {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the image from S3
    Storage.get('compression-img/11ee-bbb5-a5d6898a-382c--00155dc60818.webp') // Replace with your S3 object key
      .then(result => {
        setImageUrl(result);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching the image:', error);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      ) : (
        <FastImage
          source={{ uri: imageUrl }}
          style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```